# Does Sitecore.Context.Item make use of HttpContext?

Tags: c#, sitecore, httpcontext, sitecore6

Does Sitecore make use of the HttpContext to save needless calls to the DB?

Specifically for the context item and database?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Take a look at Sitecore.Caching.ItemsContext. It uses `HttpContext.Current.Items` to save the context Item. The context database is in there as well.